# Reusable Content in SharePoint 2010 lists?

Tags: list, reusable

Reusable Contents works fine in Pages but is there any way to use Reusable Contents in SharePoint lists (Multiline column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll only work if you use the Publishing HTML field in your list (which is what's used on Publishing Pages), rather than standard multi line text field. This is because only the Publishing HTML list has the ribbon actions which allow you to insert Reusable Content, and allow the content to be updated from the Reusable Content list.